# Parameter changes when Cell Value changes?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Website URL serves as the source where changing a Parameter changes URL address, is there a way to change the parameter from within a cell/worksheet and not change the parameter in Power Q/ BI each time I need to change the URL source which is inconvenient.

I have tried a "merged" query of sorts where I don't use a parameter but use a drilldown query that does change when the cell value changes but I get a firewall prompt regarding the new query not having permission to access the source (Website)
I have tried having the parameter reference another query (same issue as the first attempt).

' --> This retrieves the data from yahoo! where the parameter that changes is the ticker "& ticker &".

```
let

Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & ticker & "/history?period1=1279173600&period2=2000000000&interval=" & #"time frame" & "&filter=history&" & "frequency=" & #"time frame")),
Data2 = Source{2}[Data],

in

Data2
```

---

'--> Parameter for ticker

```
    "PG" meta [IsParameterQuery=true, Type="Any",
```

### IsParameterQueryRequired=true]

I want to change cell $A$1 in a sheet and that will change the parameter 'ticker"

I do know decent VBA but have not used it yet in fixing this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is tagged with "powerbi", however you are talking about cells and VBA. Are you sure you are using correct tags?

Answer (score 1):

You can use list of excel cell values as parameter by invoking function in your source query. Check the link which explains well about the scenario,

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/tech-tip-thursday-dynamic-power-bi-reports-using-parameters/